# How to create a better modal for editing function

Tags: javascript, html

I created a modal that pops up when the user clicks the edit button, I set this up with HTML

```
<div class="budget-update"></div>
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Want to make changes?</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="budget-update">
                        <select id="cashflow-update" name="income/expense" class="income/expense">
                            <option class="options-update" value="income">Income</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="expense">Expense</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="catagory-update" name="Catagory" value="Catagory">
                            <option class="options-update" value="House Hold">House Hold</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="Car">Car</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="investments">Investments</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="business">Business</option>
                            <option class="options-update" value="savings">Savings</option>
                        </select>
                         <input class="label-update" type="text" placeholder="Example rent">
                        <input class="number-update" type="number" placeholder="0,0">
                        </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <img src="/resources/Images/Save-icon.png" alt="Save Icon">
                </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and linked it with the edit button using javascript

```
const el = {
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  cashflow: document.querySelector("#cashflow"),
  catagory: document.querySelector(".catagory"),
  label: document.querySelector(".label"),
  number: document.querySelector(".number"),
  modal:document.querySelector(".modal"),
};

/*----Edit budget Entry----*/
function editItem(){
modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

but I realize that is the wrong approach if I would like to have the edit pop up with its current information to have it changed.

Currently as it stands is that the pop up does appear, but the issue I will have is that the new edited information will not replace the old one

This is the information for the list

```
/*----Render Budget List----*/
function renderList(){

  window.localStorage.getItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY)

el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>`
;
});

el.label.value="";
el.number.value="";

}
```

What I would like the outcome to be is that when the user clicks the edit button the pop-up appears with the existing data that was created in the list, but when the information changes it replaces the old data.

Please find the whole js code here

```
/*----Storage key----*/

const BUDGETLIST_KEY = "user-key-entryList";

/*----Generate ID----*/

const createId = () =>`${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${(new Date().getTime())}`;

/*----Get current Date----*/

function createdDate() {

  let currentDate = new Date();

  let day = String(currentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  let month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  let year = currentDate.getFullYear();

  currentDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  return currentDate;
}


/*----Variable Objects----*/
const el = {
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  cashflow: document.querySelector("#cashflow"),
  catagory: document.querySelector(".catagory"),
  label: document.querySelector(".label"),
  number: document.querySelector(".number"),
  modal:document.querySelector(".modal"),
};

/*----Array with local Storage----*/

let budgetArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY) ?? "[]");

/*----Budget list Object----*/

function makeNewBudget(){
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    cashflowNew: el.cashflow.value,
    catagoryNew: el.catagory.value,
    labelNew: el.label.value,
    dateNew: createdDate(),
    numberNew: el.number.value,
  };
  return data;
}

/*----Render Budget List----*/
function renderList(){

  window.localStorage.getItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY)

el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>`
;
});

el.label.value="";
el.number.value="";

}

/*----keep list after browser refreshed----*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  renderList()
})

/*----form validation----*/
let budgetButton = document.querySelector(".budget-button");

let label = document.querySelector(".label");
let num = document.querySelector(".number");

budgetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (!label.value || !num.value) {
    alert("please make sure all inputs are filled");
  }
  
  budgetArray.push(makeNewBudget())

  renderList();

  storedEntry();
  
});

/*----Remove from array----*/
function deleteItem(event, i){
  budgetArray.splice(i, 1);

  storedEntry()

  renderList();
  
}

/*----Close Modal----*/
let close = document.querySelector(".btn-close")
let xBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-secondary")
let modal= document.querySelector(".modal")

close.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if(close){
    modal.style.display = "none"
  }

});

xBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if(xBtn){
    modal.style.display = "none"
  }

});

/*----Edit budget Entry----*/
function editItem(){
modal.style.display = "block";
}



/*----Store Stored budget list----*/
function storedEntry(){
    window.localStorage.setItem(BUDGETLIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(budgetArray));
}
```

Comment: You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? local storage is already been used, do you mean localStorage in the ```function editItem```?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could save the inputs' values to localStorage in an `input` event listener, and retrieve those values when opening the modal.

Comment: okay thank you, I will try that, that idea just might work.